# Facebook SDK is not getting recognized in android studio

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-build

I have added the below mentioned dependency and the repositories. But even after Sync and Rebuild, Facebook is not getting added and hence the import is not happening in the java file. This is as per the document provided by facebook. I have similar setup in other app. Please let me know if I am missing anything, I am trying to resolve this for more than a day. Please assist.

in module level build.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
compileSdkVersion 28

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }

    androidTest.setRoot('tests')
}
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
api project(':BaseGameUtils')
api files('libs/AudienceNetwork.jar')
api files('libs/FacebookAdapter.jar')
implementation files('libs/chartboost.jar')
implementation files('libs/chartboost-7.2.0.1.aar')
api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

api 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.1'

api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.1'
api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.1'
api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1'
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1'
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:15.0.1'
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1'
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
}
```

[image]
[image]

Also tried this dependency, still not resolved
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**add this instead**

```
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you don't have 'Offline Work' enabled

File > Settings  (or Preferences on Mac)  > Gradle

Under Global Gradle settings, uncheck 'Offline work' (if checked).

Click 'OK'.

I was having the same issue, this resolved it for me.